# Angular Application only root path works on Apache Web Server

Tags: angular, apache, amazon-ec2

I am deploying an Angular 4 application on an EC2 instance. I compiled the application with `ng build --prod` and moved the contents of the `dist` directory to `/var/www/html`. Furthermore, I have started the web service daemon with `sudo service httpd start`. The webpage works except that I can only access routes via the main page.

For example I can get to:

```
http://my-page.com/dashboard
```

only by first visiting

```
http://my-page.com
```

and then clicking on the dashboard button. However, I cannot access this portion of the application directly by navigating to `http://my-page.com/dachboard` as was possible in the the angular development environment (Angular CLI server).

I would like to know if this is possible and how to achieve this. The steps that I have taken to try to resolve this are

1. Enable `mod_proxy` by adding `RewriteEnging On` and adding `ProxyPass * http://my-page.com/` and `ProxyPassReverse * http://my-page.com/` to the `httpd.conf` file
2. Try to add `AllowOverride All` to the `httpd.conf` file
3. Configuring `.htaccess` to allow RewiteEngine.

Comment: Ugh, this thing that is HTML5 mode. I still fight it on different platforms. Haven't hit this one yet though, have you seen this? It sounds like you are on the right track. https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess. Interesting note in there I hadn't thought of before, this can affect SEO.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this article](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Deploying-prod-build-to-Apache-2) describing how to deploy an Angular application on Apache. The steps you missed are adding:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

to `.htaccess` and adding

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

to the `<VirtualHost *:80>` section of `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file. That should do the trick.

Comment: Someone remind me to mark this as the correct answer.